# Active admin has_many through delete association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, activeadmin

I'm currently making association like this :

```
show do
  h3 project.title
  panel "Utilisateurs" do
    table_for project.roles do
      column "Prenom" do |role|
        role.user.firstname
      end
      column "Nom" do |role|
        role.user.lastname
      end
      column "email" do |role|
        role.user.email
      end
      column "Role" do |role|
        role.role_name.name
      end
    end
  end
end

# override default form
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do # Project's fields
    f.input :title
    f.input :code
  end

  f.has_many :roles do |app_f|
    app_f.inputs do
      # if object has id we can destroy it
      if app_f.object.id
        app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Supprimer l'utilisateur du projet"
      end
      app_f.input :user,      :include_blank => false, :label_method => :to_label
      app_f.input :role_name, :include_blank => false 
    end
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

I have the following associations :

**Project**

```
has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy 
has_many :users, :through => :role
```

**User**

```
has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :projects, :through => :role
```

**Role**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :role_name
```

**RoleName**

```
has_many :roles
```

When I try to destroy user association through my form nothing happen, any idea to solve this ?
Or to add delete link to my show block ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to your Project model (and `roles_attributes` to attr_accessible):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy 
    has_many :users, :through => :role
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :allow_destroy => true

    attr_accessible :roles_attributes, (+ all you had here before)
    ... 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

**allow_destroy: true** is the root of this issue.